# Alert Meassage Box Issue

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I have an alert message for displaying the message of validation. But it includes one - symbol. I did not add this symbol on code. 
my code is shown below.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Login :</font>
  </td>
  <td>
    <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLogin" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Validator1" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Login Id is Required" ControlToValidate="txtLogin"
        Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <font face="Verdana" size="2">Password :</font>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" 
      TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Validator2" runat="server"
      ErrorMessage="Password is required" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
      Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

The error message box image appended below:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5483913c72.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5483913c72.jpg).

How we could avoid this symbol?

Comment: Are you serious about using tables for layout and `font` instead of CSS? This looks like code from the nineties to me.

Comment: ASP.NET generates a list of all the errors and is responsible for the - sign. Can you show the javascript code that displays this error message? Maybe you can remove the - before showing the alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is a function of your `ValidationSummary`. Specifically the `DisplayMode` property. Check out the [DisplayMode reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.displaymode(VS.80).aspx) and the corresponding [ValidationSummaryDisplayMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummarydisplaymode(VS.80).aspx).